# How to import csv data into postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I tried to import csv file data into postgres table. Running the following line as pgscript in pgAdmin

```
\copy users_page_rank FROM E'C:\\Users\\GamulinN\\Desktop\\users page rank.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV
```

it returned an error:

```
[ERROR    ] 1.0: syntax error, unexpected character
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong here? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table) post but couldn't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: `\copy` is as `psql` command. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To import file into postgres with `COPY` you need one of the following:

1) Connect with `psql` to the DB and run your comand:

```
\copy users_page_rank FROM E'C:\\Users\\GamulinN\\Desktop\\users page rank.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV
```

It will copy the file from current computer to the table. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

2) Connect with any tool to the DB and run this SQL script:

```
COPY users_page_rank FROM E'C:\\Users\\GamulinN\\Desktop\\users page rank.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV
```

It will copy the file from the server with postgres  to the table. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). (With this command you can only `COPY` from files in postgresql **data directory**. So you will need to transfer files there first.)