# Can I automatically create a table in PostgreSQL from a csv file with headers?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.2.6 on OS X 10.6.8. I would like to import data from a CSV file with column headers into a database. I can do this with the `COPY` statement, but only if I first manually create a table with a column for each column in the CSV file. Is there any way to automatically create this table based on the headers in the CSV file?

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662631/how-to-copy-from-csv-file-to-postgresql-table-with-headers-in-csv-file) I have tried

`COPY test FROM '/path/to/test.csv' CSV HEADER;`

But I just get this error:

`ERROR:  relation "test" does not exist`

And if I first create a table with no columns:

`CREATE TABLE test ();`

I get:

`ERROR:  extra data after last expected column`

I can't find anything in the PostgreSQL [COPY documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) about automatically creating a table. Is there some other way to automatically create a table from a CSV file with headers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't find anything in the [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) documentation, because COPY **cannot** create a table for you.
You need to do that before you can `COPY` to it.

Comment: This answer does actually not answer his question 

Comment: This answer should be a comment, and not be accepted as it does not answer the question.

Comment: This is not an answer!

Answer (score 72):

There is a very good tool that imports tables into Postgres from a csv file.
It is a command-line tool called pgfutter ([with binaries for windows, linux, etc.](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter/releases)). One of its big advantages is that it recognizes the attribute/column names as well.

The usage of the tool is simple. For example if you'd like to import `myCSVfile.csv`:

```
pgfutter --db "myDatabase" --port "5432" --user "postgres" --pw "mySecretPassword" csv myCSVfile.csv
```

This will create a table (called `myCSVfile`) with the column names taken from the csv file's header. Additionally the data types will be identified from the existing data.

A few notes: The command `pgfutter` varies depending on the binary you use, e.g. it could be `pgfutter_windows_amd64.exe` (rename it if you intend to use this command frequently). The above command has to be executed in a command line window (e.g. in Windows run `cmd` and ensure `pgfutter` is accessible). If you'd like to have a different table name add `--table "myTable"`; to select a particular database schema us `--schema "mySchema"`. In case you are accessing an external database use `--host "myHostDomain"`.

A more elaborate example of `pgfutter` to import `myFile` into `myTable` is this one:

```
pgfutter --host "localhost" --port "5432" --db "myDB" --schema "public" --table "myTable" --user "postgres" --pw "myPwd" csv myFile.csv
```

Most likely you will change a few data types (from text to numeric) after the import:

```
alter table myTable
  alter column myColumn type numeric
    using (trim(myColumn)::numeric)
```

Comment: I requires the destination table and columns to be created if I specify a schema name. Frustrating

Comment: This tool is presently failing with an "index out of range" exception when you try to import a CSV file.

Comment: There is no option to change the delimiter. :-(

Comment: Looks like you can change the delimiter now, for example to use tab: `pgfutter csv -d $'\t' traffic_violations.csv`.

Comment: At this point in time this app "just works" for me under CentOS 8.

Comment: Can create tables and columns dynamically with delimiter and other options.. Nice tool.

Comment: For some reason this tool exited with "Killed" message after trying to import a 250mb CSV. However, it managed to create the database based on the CSV header, which had about 50 columns. This was good enough for me, because it allowed me to import the data using PgAdmin.

Comment: I run this command with various options after checking --help and it does nothing and outputs nothing. An error would be nice

Comment: is there a way to avoid typing actual password in the psql command line? instead, prompted password section would be ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, `pgfutter` appears to be a stalled project that fails to provide reasonable error messaging.

Answer (score 39):

There is a second approach, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table) (from mmatt). Basically you call a function within Postgres (last argument specifies the number of columns).

```
select load_csv_file('myTable','C:/MyPath/MyFile.csv',24)
```

Here is mmatt's function code, which I had to modify slightly, because I am working on the public schema. (copy&paste into PgAdmin SQL Editor and run it to create the function)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_csv_file(
    target_table text,
    csv_path text,
    col_count integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or spreadsheet

begin
    set schema 'public';

    create table temp_table ();

    -- add just enough number of columns
    for iter in 1..col_count
    loop
        execute format('alter table temp_table add column col_%s text;', iter);
    end loop;

    -- copy the data from csv file
    execute format('copy temp_table from %L with delimiter '','' quote ''"'' csv ', csv_path);

    iter := 1;
    col_first := (select col_1 from temp_table limit 1);

    -- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
    for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(trim(temp_table::text, ''()''), '','')) from temp_table where col_1 = %L', col_first)
    loop
        execute format('alter table temp_table rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
        iter := iter + 1;
    end loop;

    -- delete the columns row
    execute format('delete from temp_table where %s = %L', col_first, col_first);

    -- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
    if length(target_table) > 0 then
        execute format('alter table temp_table rename to %I', target_table);
    end if;

end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION load_csv_file(text, text, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Note: There is a common issue with importing text files related to encoding. The csv file should be in UTF-8 format. However, sometimes this is not quite achieved by the programs, which try to do the encoding. I have overcome this issue by opening the file in Notepad++ and converting it to ANSI and back to UTF8.

Comment: This is a tidy solution. Take care to ensure that none of the columns have reserved keyword names - e.g., if the CSV file has a column called `order` (for order numbers, say) change it to `order_num`. Also, remember to change column `TYPE` as required.

Comment: This solutions fails because it tries to open the CSV file in the server, not in the client. You would need access to the file system of the server for something like this to work.

Comment: How do we make this use the CSV file on the local machine? I believe it is looking for the file on the server. ERROR:  must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file
HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.

Comment: I suggest using quote_ident(col_first), in order to handle column names with mixed case.

Answer (score 36):

Use sqlite as intermediate step.

Steps:

1. In the command prompt type: `sqlite3`
2. In the sqlite3 CLI type: `.mode csv`
3. `.import my_csv.csv my_table`
4. `.output my_table_sql.sql`
5. `.dump my_table`
6. Finally execute that sql in your Postgresql

Comment: TIL sqlite has nice import tools! Thanks this worked great for me.

Comment: this is such a nice solution, kudos

Comment: This is brilliant, a really elegant approach. In addition, sqlite is usually powerful enough to do anything you might have needed from postgres

Comment: How would I modify this to create the table in a specific schema, such as "dbo" ?

Comment: Fyi, all columns will be of type text as sqlite3 doesn't try to infer data types.

Answer (score 33):

I am using `csvsql` to generate the table layout (it will automatically guess the format):

```
head -n 20 table.csv | csvsql --no-constraints --tables table_name
```

And then I use `\COPY` in `psql`. That's for me the fastest way to import CSV file.

You can also use `sed` with `csvsql` in order to get the desired datatype:

```
head -n 20 table.csv | csvsql --no-constraints --tables table_name  | sed 's/DECIMAL/NUMERIC/' | sed 's/VARCHAR/TEXT/' | sed 's/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP'
```

Comment: Hi I quite like this psql solution, but when I execute it returns a syntax erreur on or near "head"   (I don't often use psql...)

Comment: @lhowarth : head is a linux (shell) command, not a SQL command. You should run "head..." in a linux terminal, not in the psql client. "head -n 20 table.csv" will return the first 20 rows of the csv file. Then you pipe (|) it to scvsql... then you use \COPY in psql.

Answer (score 9):

Automatic creation seems to be pretty easy with Python+Pandas

Install sqlalchemy library in your Python environment
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.31

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase')
df=pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df.to_sql('table_name', engine)
```

Answer (score 4):

I achieved it with this steps:

1. Convert the csv file to utf8

```
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file.txt -o file.csv
```

2. Use this python script to create the sql to create table and copy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv, os
#pip install python-slugify
from slugify import slugify

origem = 'file.csv'
destino = 'file.sql'
arquivo = os.path.abspath(origem)

d = open(destino,'w')
with open(origem,'r') as f:

    header = f.readline().split(';')
    head_cells = []
    for cell in header:
        value = slugify(cell,separator="_")
        if value in head_cells:
            value = value+'_2'
        head_cells.append(value)
    #cabecalho = "{}\n".format(';'.join(campos))

    #print(cabecalho)
    fields= []
    for cell in head_cells:
        fields.append(" {} text".format(cell))
    table = origem.split('.')[0]
    sql = "create table {} ( \n {} \n);".format(origem.split('.')[0],",\n".join(fields))
    sql += "\n COPY {} FROM '{}' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;".format(table,arquivo)

    print(sql)
    d.write(sql)
```

3.Run the  script with

```
python3 importar.py
```

Optional: Edit the sql script to adjust the field types (all are text by default)

4. Run the sql script. Short for console

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "psql mydatabase < file.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but pgLoader (https://pgloader.io/) is recommended by the pgfutter developers (see answer above) for more complicated problems.  It looks very capable.

Comment: I tried using this and couldn't find a way to have it create a table for you with a csv input. (it appears you still need to write the create table statement)

Comment: Yes it looks like [you're right](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/csv.html) that it requires the `create table` statement; I hadn't noticed that.  I guess the main use is for more complicated situations like on-the-fly transforms during loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new table in [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Data-transfer/) out of a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

For a single table, I did very simply, quickly and online through one of the many good converters that can be found on the web.
Just google [convert csv to sql online](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20csv%20to%20sql%20online&oq=convert%20csv%20to%20sql%20online&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.754j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and choose one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it -
Create table for the CSV file

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    column1 INT,
    column2 VARCHAR(255),
    column3 VARCHAR(255),
    -- Add more columns as needed
);

-- Import data from the CSV file into table
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' -- Use the correct delimiter
ENCLOSED BY '"' -- Use the correct enclosing character if needed
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- Use the correct line terminator
IGNORE 1 LINES; -- Skip the header if needed
```

- Note - Remember to replace `/path/to/your/file.csv`  with the actual paths to your CSV files. Also, adjust the table and column names, as well as data types, to match your CSV files.

Comment: Could improve the formatting.