# Can I import CSV data into a table without knowing the columns of the CSV?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a CSV file `file.csv`.

In Postgres, I have made a table named `grants`:

```
CREATE TABLE grants
(

)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE grants
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I want to import `file.csv` data without having to specify columns in Postgres.

But if I run `COPY grants FROM '/PATH/TO/grants.csv' CSV HEADER;`, I get this error: `ERROR:  extra data after last expected column`.

How do I import the CSV data without having to specify columns and types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018256/can-i-automatically-create-a-table-in-postgresql-from-a-csv-file-with-headers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I automatically create a table in PostgreSQL from a csv file with headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018256/can-i-automatically-create-a-table-in-postgresql-from-a-csv-file-with-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is normal.
You created a table with no column. The [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command try to import data into the table with the good structure.
So you have to create the table corresponding to your csv file before execute the COPY command.

I discovered [pgfutter](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter) :

"Import CSV and JSON into PostgreSQL the easy way. This small tool abstract all the hassles and swearing you normally have to deal with when you just want to dump some data into the database"

Perhaps a solution ...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible using the COPY command

> If a list of columns is specified, COPY will only copy the data in the
>   specified columns to or from the file. If there are any columns in the
>   table that are not in the column list, COPY FROM will insert the
>   default values for those columns.

COPY does not create columns for you.

Answer (score -1):

The best method for me was to convert the csv to dataframe and then follow

> https://github.com/sp-anna-jones/data_science/wiki/Importing-pandas-dataframe-to-postgres