# Unable to load CSV file in postgresq due to column of relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a csv file :

```
SrNo,TradeDate,TradeTime,SettlementNo
1,25-Apr-17,14:48:19,NSE-N-2017077
2,05-May-17,09:33:28,NSE-N-2017084
```

I am trying to upload this file using the command:

```
copy public.shares(SrNo,TradeDate,TradeTime,SettlementNo) from 'C:/Users/Dell/Downloads/report_jul2018.csv' with csv header;
```

It is giving the error:

```
ERROR: column "srno" of relation "shares" does not exist SQL state: 42703
```

Any solution?

Comment: What columns does shares have? perhaps you need to say `"SrNo"`?

Comment: I have added the file header and the query above. I am running the same query.

Comment: yeah, but how is the table defined?  that error message says that `srno` is not the name of one of it's columns.

Comment: i have just created the table...i have not added the columns. Shoudn't the columns get defined from the csv header?

Comment: no. `header` just makes the CSV reader skip past the first record.

Comment: CSV data is untyped, the database does not know what type of columns to put in the table.

Comment: what would be the correct approach ? create the columns first ?

Comment: Is there a way to add the columns while loading the csv? like Mysql..

Comment: yes, create the columns first. I know of no way to auto-create them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I automatically create a table in PostgreSQL from a csv file with headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018256/can-i-automatically-create-a-table-in-postgresql-from-a-csv-file-with-headers)

Comment: Saw this issue recently, I had created the table with alembic. I tried to copy with bash and it failed. I got rid of the capital letters in the column names and imported the data successfully.