# Import CSV with many columns to pgAdmin v4.1

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin-4

I'm new to pgAdmin and GIS DB in general. I want to upload a CSV file to pgAdmin v4.1 and I'm trying to understand the logic to do so. I am able to do this by creating a new table under the desired DB and then manually defined the column (name, type etc.), only then I am able to load the CSV into pgAdmin using the GUI. This seems a bit cumbersome way to import a CSV file, because let's say I have a CSV file with 200 columns, it is not practical to define them all manually, and there must be a way to tell pgAdmin: this is the CSV file, now get the columns by yourself and get (or at least assume) the columns type, ad create a new table, much similar to how `pandas` reads CSV in python. As I'm new to this topic, please elaborate your answer\comment as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**: Unfortunately, we can only import CSV after the table is created.

YES: There is no GUI method, but:

1. There is a utility called pgFutter which will do exactly what you want. This is a command line utility. [Here are the binaries](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter/releases/tag/v1.2).
2. You can write a function that does that. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884609/1245195).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using GDAL to upload your CSV file into postgis.
I used this recently to do a similar job.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry -lco FID=gid PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=username dbname=dbname password=********" postgres.vrt -nln th_new_data_2019 -t_srs EPSG:27700
```

Code used to upload a csv to postgis and transform the coordinate system.

-f = file format name

output file format name, some possible values are:
     -f "ESRI Shapefile"
     -f "TIGER"
     -f "MapInfo File"
     -f "GML"
     -f "PostgreSQL

-lco = NAME=VALUE:
Layer creation option (format specific)

-nln name:
Assign an alternate name to the new layer

-t_srs srs_def:
target spatial reference set. The coordinate systems that can be passed are anything supported by the OGRSpatialReference.SetFromUserInput() call, which includes EPSG PCS and GCSes (i.e. EPSG:4296), PROJ.4 declarations (as above), or the name of a .prj file containing well known text.

The best and simplest guide for installing GDAL that I have used is :
https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

Comment: hi, thanks for the answers, but I eventually used QGIS as a mediator for that, meaning that I uploaded the CSV to QGIS and from QGIS to PgAdmin using the DB manager

Comment: Using QGIS is the best solution I think, it's also dealing with encoding problems. Because my CSV contains Chinese characters as column names, other methods can not correctly import even when I already use the UTF-8 encoding.