# Import data from CSV file to postgres database according to conditions

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, import-from-excel

Can you please tell me if there is a way to export data from CSV file to postgress database according to conditions?

By condition I mean a situation where there are two tables in a postgres database. I have to do a validation before adding a row to the second table. I need to check that a parameter in my file matches the value in the first table and only if that parameter matches I need to put that parameter in the second table.

For example, I have two tables "clothing brand" and "clothing size". The CSV file that needs to be exported to postgres table contains both the brand of clothing and its sizes. I need to make a validation in the tables already created in postgres, that if the brand of clothing that is in the csv file exists already in the table, then I need to add or modify the table "clothing size".

I tried searching the internet, but found examples of how to simply import a complete table from CSV file to postgres database.
[any way to import a csv file to postgresql without creating new tables from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867431/any-way-to-import-a-csv-file-to-postgresql-without-creating-new-tables-from-scra)
[How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKjcwBUxZXY
But I couldn't find an example where I could first check the existing table data and only after successful results of this verification I could insert a specific row.

Comment: Use a `INSERT` trigger on the first table.

Comment: thank you. Could you please advise me how this trigger could read the value of CSV file at runtime on postgres database?

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information. 1) The table definitions. 2) Example data. 3) Example (pseudo)code of what you are trying to achieve. **Add information as text as update to question text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to import all data into a temporary table using `COPY` command, and then use standard SQL queries to filter out and insert only specific rows. It would look something like this:

```
create table temp_sizes (...);
copy temp_sizes from 'sizes.csv' format CSV;
insert into sizes from temp_sizes where brand_name in (select name from brands);
drop table temp_sizes;
```

Alternatively, you could use any general-purpose programming language to parse the CSV file and issue `INSERT` commands according to your conditions.