# Unable to import a csv file in PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to import a large csv file into PgAdmin using the built-in import feature and receiving a "column" error.

I also tried the following query for the table I'm creating:

```
COPY CovidDeaths 
FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\SQL_Portfolio\CovidDeaths.csv'
Delimiter ','
CSV Header;
```

Error: "ERROR:  relation "coviddeaths" does not exist"

[image]

I have tried Big 5 and UTF-8 encoding and both result in the same vague error "column." As far as I understand from the documentation, If I leave the column field blank it will import all the columns. However, I can't get past the "columns" error. There are 300 + columns, so it wouldn't be feasible to manually create them. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: "*vague error "column."*" - that's not what "*ERROR: relation "coviddeaths" does not exist*" is?

Comment: "*it wouldn't be feasible to manually create them*" - there's no way around that. `COPY` does not create a table or add columns to an existing table. It just moves data.

Comment: Are you sure this is not an occurrence due to case mismatch??

Comment: SO there's no way to just import a csv file that will create a table?

Comment: No. See [Can I automatically create a table in PostgreSQL from a csv file with headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018256/can-i-automatically-create-a-table-in-postgresql-from-a-csv-file-with-headers)

Comment: Do you even *need* all 300 columns? What are the types of the columns?

Comment: You can't do that with Postgres `COPY`. There are a variety of third party tools that do that though. To name one: [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in particular [csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: relation "coviddeaths" . That one just doesn't exist, you didn't create it. However, based on the image you posted, you did create a table with almost (!) the same name: CovidDeaths. But this table uses upper case characters. You just found out why it's a bad idea to use upper case. Never use it, to avoid problems. And if you really really want to use it, you must always use double quotes " around the name: "CovidDeaths". Every time you forget this, you get the same error message again.

This SQL uses the double quotes, and might work:

```
COPY "CovidDeaths" 
FROM 'C:\Users\Desktop\SQL_Portfolio\CovidDeaths.csv'
WITH (
Delimiter ',',
FORMAT CSV ,
Header);
```

Comment: That still won't work since the OP has not defined any columns in that table

Comment: @Bergi That's an issue... But he even didn't get to that error because the table name was wrong.