# Is possible to use STDIN with CREATE FOREIGN TABLE?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I was looking for the STDIN option, to use FOREIGN TABLE in similar way as COPY... And discovery a "bug" in the Guide: there are no documentation about options at [official sql-create-foreign-table Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html). No link, nothing:

> OPTIONS ( option 'value' [, ...] )
>
> Options to be associated with the new foreign table or one of its columns. ...

So, to lack of information transformed this  question in two:

1. **It is possible to use STDIN with `FOREIGN TABLE`?**
2. Where the "OPTIONS" documentation?

---

### edit to add example

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE t1 (
   aa text,
   bb bigint
) SERVER files OPTIONS (
   filename '/tmp/bigBigdata.csv',
   format 'csv',
   header 'true'
;
```

Is a classic ugly PostgreSQL limitation on use filesystem, so I need a terminal  solution ... Imagine on shell something with pipes, as

```
psql  -c "ALTER FOREIGN TABLE t1 ...  STDIN; CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT trim(aa) as aa, bb+1 as bb FROM t WHERE bb>999" < /thePath/bigBigdata.csv
```

Is a kind of "no direct copy, only filtering a stream of data", and creating a final table t2 from this filtered stream.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused about foreign tables, I'll try to explain.

1. The data of a foreign table do not reside in PostgreSQL, but in an external data source (a file, a different database, etc.).

   The foreign table is just a way to access these data from PostgreSQL as if they were a PostgreSQL table.

   You can `COPY` to a foreign table `FROM STDIN` if the foreign data wrapper supports it, but that has nothing to with `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`. `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` defines how PostgreSQL should locate the external data and what the format of the data is.
2. There is no documentation of the options in `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` because they depend on the foreign data wrapper you are using.

   Look at the documentation of the foreign data wrapper.

Your example makes clear that what you need is not a foreign table, but a temporary table into which you can `COPY` the raw data which you later want to modify. You cannot use `file_fdw` for data that resides on the client machine.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, sorry, I was looking for a  file-permission solution in CSV bigbig files, I edited to illustrate... About the "bug of the Guide", the lack of `*_fdw`  modules citation (and no  link) **is a bug**.  Thanks to the clues, now I can see that there are *nothing about STDIN* at [`file_fdw` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html). My workaround is to use a "foreign language" (as [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) to interact with the filesystem without ugly permission barriers) instead the *foreigin table* approach.

Comment: Most of the foreign data wrappers are not part of the PostgreSQL project, so they have no place in the documentation. Look at the PostgreSQL Wiki for a comprehensive list. Your use case is still not well described; perhaps `COPY ... FROM PROGRAM`is what you need.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, I was navegating and see, 2 years after, a better example for you: [**ingestion** from relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464864/287948)... In ETL/bigdata terminology "ingestion" describes a class of problems to be solved. The dream for PostgreSQL is to *ingest* any CSV file of a fixed structure (`my_foreign_stdin` or a projection from it)... In the dream the terminal command would be something as `psql _etc_ -c  "INSERT INTO  mytable SELECT column1::bigint, trim(column2) FROM my_foreign_stdin WHERE column1>10" < ./relative_path/file.csv`

Comment: Replace `INSERT` with `COPY`, and you are almost there. v12 offers a `WHERE` clause for `COPY`. All you need are some pre-processing steps (`sed`?) or post-processing (unlogged table, `UPDATE`, `ALTER TABLE ... SET LOGGED`).