# Download HTTP data with Postgres StoredProcedure

Tags: postgresql, http

I am wondering if there is a way to import data from an HTTP source from within an pgsql function.

I am porting an old system that harvests data from a website. Rather than maintaining a separate set of files to manage the downloading of the data, I was hoping to put the import routines directly into stored procedures.

I do know how to import data with COPY, but that requires the data to already be available locally. Is there a way to get the download the data with PL/PGSQL? Am I out to lunch?

Related: [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending what you're after, the Postgres extension `www_fdw` might work for you: `http://pgxn.org/dist/www_fdw/`

Comment: As it is a CSV I am downloading, this also relevant in my case http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/file-fdw.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want download custom data by HTTP protocol, then PostgreSQL extensive support for different languages might be handy. Here is the example of connecting to Google Translate service from Postgres function written in Python:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Google_Translate

Comment: This is a very good answer. This may be easier to implement, and may offer more options in the future.