# How to import data from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have table `A` (MySQL) and table `B` (PostgreSQL)

I want to include all existing records in table `A` to table `B`

Could this be done?

Thank you

Comment: I assume you're using to different DB-systems. Try to export the data to a common format (e.g. XML), which  you can import into the destination table.

Answer (score 0):

I used MYSQL work bench (https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for migration of MS SQL to Mysql. The schema got converted but that data didn't get transferred. Probably because my database size was 1.5GB. I would recommend you to give it a try and I am sure that will work in your case. It shows the detailed logs in case of failure and pretty robust.

Comment: This is not an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Export table into csv

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

and then import it into postgresql

[How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

**e.g.**

```
SELECT * FROM A
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/data.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';


// must be same column as csv file
create table B  (....)

COPY B(column_1, column_2, . . . . ) FROM 'C:/tmp/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

if you are using pgadmin3 then simple follow this answer to import csv file into postgresql

[How should I import data from CSV into a Postgres table using pgAdmin 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400173/how-should-i-import-data-from-csv-into-a-postgres-table-using-pgadmin-3)