# insert from CSV file to PostgreSQL table with integer values type

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, integer, psycopg2

```
  I want to insert data from a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table. The table
```

structure is given below. But I am unable to give input of INTEGER type values.
It is showing error like- 
        DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "vendor_phone"
        LINE 1: ...vendor_phone,vendor_address)VALUES ('vendor_name','vendor_ph...

It is working fine if I use VARCHAR type. But i need to use integer values.

```
   CREATE TABLE vendors (
        vendor_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        vendor_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        vendor_phone INTEGER,
        vendor_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
    )
```

---

```
    import psycopg2
    import csv

    database = psycopg2.connect (database = "supplier", user="postgres", password="1234", host="localhost", port="5432")
```

cursor = database.cursor()

```
    vendor_data = csv.reader(open('vendors.csv'),delimiter=',')

    for row in vendor_data:

        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO vendors (vendor_name,vendor_phone,vendor_address)"\
            "VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
           row)

    print("CSV data imported")

    cursor.close()
    database.commit()
    database.close()
```

Comment: Look at the error message carefully, it says you're inserting the word "vendor_phone" which clearly isn't an integer. It sounds like you have a header row which you need to skip.

Comment: Refer this links .. Might be helpful to you...

(1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table

(2)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400173/how-should-i-import-data-from-csv-into-a-postgres-table-using-pgadmin-3

Comment: I need to give input of a integer value....Further I have some porthin of my code-- header = next(vendor_data)
rows = [header] + [[row[0], int(row[1]), row[2]] for row in vendor_data]

for row in rows:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO vendors (vendor_name,vendor_phone,vendor_address)"\
                "VALUES (%s,%??,%s)",
               row)

Answer (score 1):

instead of cursor, you can use below statement to load data directly from CSV to table which skips Header of the CSV file

```
COPY vendors (vendor_name,vendor_phone,vendor_address) FROM 'vendors.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: I need to insert an integer value ....Further I have edited some portion of my code-- header = next(vendor_data)
rows = [header] + [[row[0], int(row[1]), row[2]] for row in vendor_data]

for row in rows:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO vendors (vendor_name,vendor_phone,vendor_address)"\
                "VALUES (%s,%d,%s)",
               row) ----it is giving error -ValueError: unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index %Id

Comment: From your suggestion I have tried the copy command-
        cursor.execute("COPY vendor_parts 
        (vendor_id,part_book_id,time_id,total_sale) 
        FROM 'D:\vendor_parts.csv' CSV HEADER;")   -----     This query is running in shell prompt, but not running in my python code.Showing error  SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal----