# Loading CSV data to a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, csv, load

What is the best way to load [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) data to a table in a [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database (in Java)?

Context: I am working on [extract, transform, load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) (ETL) processing - extracted the flat file and generated (csv's of a similar table). I want to load CSV files to a PostgreSQL table in Java.

Comment: In order to load csv data into postgres, you don't need Java. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL the usual way of copying data from a CSV file is the `COPY` statement (more information is in the [the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html)). To use this statement you must have have the file in a location readable by the server.

If the data cannot be put to the server readable location beforehand, you can use a `psql \copy` ([more information](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY)) or `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way of loading a CSV file into a PostgreSQL database is using the [`COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

From the Java side you can use the method [`copyIn` of `CopyManager` class](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html#copyIn%28java.lang.String%29) from the PostgreSQL [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) driver.