# Load CSV file from S3 to postgressql

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am new to AWS ,I have CSV file in amazon S3, now I want to read and import the CSV file in to aws postgres table using java.

I know we can use the below commands in CLI,

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.csv /mydirectory/file.csv
psql -h your_rds.amazonaws.com -U username -d dbname -c '\COPY table FROM ''file.csv'' CSV HEADER'
```

But I need to run it in java.

Can anyone please suggest me any solution.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813025/loading-csv-data-to-a-postgresql-table

Answer (score 0):

If can use other options, can explore:

[Load S3 Data into Amazon RDS MySQL Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html)

But if has to be Java, then you may AWS Lambda, as this looks to be administrative activity

1. **Read file from S3**

   [How to read S3 file from AWS Lambda Function written in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462933/how-to-read-s3-file-from-aws-lambda-function-written-in-java)
2. **Load into RDS ( code sample ):**

   [Import CSV file into mysql using Java](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/import-csv-file-to-mysql-table-java-example/)