# Ipython-sql default folder

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to load data from a CSV file into a Postgresql database using the [ipython-sql extension](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql).

I followed the example on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table) but I get error:

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not open file "./test_file.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

I suspect this is due to a default path for the extension that is different from the notebook path. I can successfully load the data if I use an absolute path, but that's ugly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use *'The absolute path name of the input or output file'* in [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) command...