# Trying to read mm/dd/yyyy format in sql while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, sql-timestamp

So I am very new in SQL and I am trying to create a table where I will later import a .csv file. In this table there is a time stamp column that I want to set it up to read mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss, yet I've tried doing this:

```
 create table Particle_counter_HiSam ( time_utc  timestamp(m/d/Y hh:mi:ss),...
```

and i get this error

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "m"
```

I just can't seem to figure this out.

Any help will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table as normal `timestamp` and use `SET` with `STR_TO_DATE` in `load data infile` as below.

```
-- table definition
create table Particle_counter_HiSam ( time_utc  timestamp, ... );

-- load data
load data infile 'data.csv' 
into table Particle_counter_HiSam
fields terminated BY ',' ESCAPED BY ""
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(@var1, c2, ....)
SET time_utc = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%S');
```

Comment: question in the load data portion I have encountered a bunch of errors with the path format this is what I typically put in the quotes 'C:\Users\Alan Cedeno\Desktop\TestFilesForSohl-Aerostat160215 Version 2.0\TestFilesForAlan-Aerostat160215\Aerostat160215\MillCreek(Particle Counter) 2-15-16\HiSAM160215\1-28-16'  and I get and error saying there is not path or directory

Comment: This is not MySQL related error. You need to find the correct path for your csv file. To have a try, you can copy your .csv file to C:\data.csv and have a try.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "data"
LINE 1: load data infile 'C:\HiSAM1_data_160206_115813'

Comment: are you using pg or mysql?

Comment: I am using postgres so pg

Comment: Then this is not the ans you want. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table

Answer (score 0):

if your creating a table for timestapm, just use this..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST 'Particle_counter_HiSam' 
{

'date_log' timestamp NOT NULL,

}
```

hope this help..