# CSV to Postgres database: "Error: extra data after last expected column"

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I am trying to convert a `.csv` file to a `postgres` database. I have set up the database with the appropriate number of columns to match the `.csv` file. I have also taken care to strip all "`,`" (comma characters) from the `.csv` file.

Here is my command I am typing into `psql`:

```
COPY newtable FROM 'path/to/file.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

I have tried everything I can think of. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table

Comment: `I have also taken care to strip all "," (comma characters) from the .csv file.` Huh? That would imply that the input consists of only one field.

Comment: First, why is this tagged python. Second, you do convert a csv into a database but import csv data into database table. Please show content f file for us to help.