# Creating a table with many columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In order to use `COPY` (in my case, from a csv file) function in PostgreSQL I need to create the destination table first.

Now, in case my table has 60 columns, for instance, it feel weird and inefficient to write manually this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
   column1 datatype,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
   .....
   column60 datatype
```

Those who use PostgreSQL - how do you ger around this issue?

Comment: You could use an ORM/driver in your language choice to dynamically do that, although I'd seriously consider if you really need 60 columns in a table.

Comment: Even if they were only 30, I want to frequently open various csv files and do various data manipulations. It makes little sense to me to create manually a table each time I want to use sql on a csv file.

Comment: In that case the best option for automating this is writing a script in your preferred language. I'd do it in Node + Knex.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `file_fdw` extension to read data from CSV files.

But unfortunately, `file_fdw` is not that convenient/flexible when you solve such tasks as reading from a CSV file with many columns. `CREATE TABLE` will work with any number of columns, but if it doesn't correspond to the CSV file, it will fail later, when performing `SELECT`. So the problem of explicit creation of table remains. However, it is possible to solve it.

Here is brute-force approach that doesn't require anything except Postgres. Written in PL/pgSQL, this function tries to create a table with one single column, and attempt to `SELECT` from it. If it fails, it drops the table and tries again, but with 2 columns. And so on, until `SELECT` is OK. All columns are of type `text` – this is quite a limitation, but it still solves the task of having ready-to-SELECT table instead of doing manual work.

```
create or replace function autocreate_table_to_read_csv(
  fdw_server text,
  csv text,
  table_name text,
  max_columns_num int default 100
) returns void as $$
declare
  i int;
  sql text;
  rec record;
begin
  execute format('drop foreign table if exists %I', table_name);
  for i in 1..max_columns_num loop
    begin
      select into sql
       format('create foreign table %I (', table_name)
          || string_agg('col' || n::text || ' text', ', ')
          || format(
            e') server %I options ( filename \'%s\', format \'csv\' );',
            fdw_server,
            csv
          )
      from generate_series(1, i) as g(n);
      raise debug 'SQL: %', sql;
      execute sql;
      execute format('select * from %I limit 1;', table_name) into rec;
      -- looks OK, so the number of columns corresponds to the first row of CSV file
      raise info 'Table % created with % column(s). SQL: %', table_name, i, sql;
      exit;
    exception when others then
      raise debug 'CSV has more than % column(s), making another attempt...', i;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Once it founds the proper number of columns, it reports about it (see `raise info`).

To see more details, run `set client_min_messages to debug;` before using the function.

Example of use:

```
test=# create server csv_import foreign data wrapper file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER

test=# set client_min_messages to debug;
SET

test=# select autocreate_table_to_read_csv('csv_import', '/home/nikolay/tmp/sample.csv', 'readcsv');
NOTICE:  foreign table "readcsv" does not exist, skipping
DEBUG:  SQL: create foreign table readcsv (col1 text) server csv_import options ( filename '/home/nikolay/tmp/sample.csv', format 'csv' );
DEBUG:  CSV has more than 1 column(s), making another attempt...
DEBUG:  SQL: create foreign table readcsv (col1 text, col2 text) server csv_import options ( filename '/home/nikolay/tmp/sample.csv', format 'csv' );
DEBUG:  CSV has more than 2 column(s), making another attempt...
DEBUG:  SQL: create foreign table readcsv (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text) server csv_import options ( filename '/home/nikolay/tmp/sample.csv', format 'csv' );
INFO:  Table readcsv created with 3 column(s). SQL: create foreign table readcsv (col1 text, col2 text, col3 text) server csv_import options ( filename '/home/nikolay/tmp/sample.csv', format 'csv' );
 autocreate_table_to_read_csv
------------------------------

(1 row)

test=# select * from readcsv limit 2;
 col1  | col2  | col3
-------+-------+-------
 1313  | xvcv  | 22
 fvbvb | 2434  | 4344
(2 rows)
```

Update: found implementation of very similar (but w/o "brute-force", requiring explicit specification of # of columns in CSV file) approach,  for `COPY .. FROM`: [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

P.S. Actually, this would be a really good task to improve `file_fdw` and `COPY .. FROM` capabilities of Postgres making them more flexible – for example, for `postgres_fdw`, there is a very handy `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA` command, which allows very quickly define remote ("foreign") objects, just with one line – it saves a lot of efforts. Having similar thing for CSV dta would be awesome.