# PostGreSQL CSV import line separator

Tags: mysql, postgresql, csv

I am trying to export data from MySQL table and import that data into the PgSQl database.

**EXPORT Script from MySQL**

```
select column_names from from table_name LIMIT 2
INTO OUTFILE 'E:/CSV_files/record_main.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY ';'
```

**PgSQL IMPORT script**

```
COPY record_main("column_names ") FROM 'E:/CSV_files/record_main.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER ',' NULL '\N'   ESCAPE ';' CSV
```

The above code is working fine for me when i am trying to export and import the CSV.

But while i am increasing the selection limit 1 to 2 or any , It causes  error.

> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
>   CONTEXT:  COPY record_main, line 1: >""12635","55025","1","ASCS","P","5320700","2015-01-01 >00:00:00",\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N,"DEED",\N,\N,\N,\N,..."

Then opened the CSV file and i manually separated the one row of data in to two row of data.

And i removed the semicolon from the end of each line.

This time it is working fine.
I think error in the line separator. My question is how can i say to the PgSQl to the line separator is this. like i given the `DELIMITER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, postgresql's [copy statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html) expects the rows to be separated by new line character(s):

> COPY FROM can handle lines ending with newlines, carriage returns, or carriage return/newlines.

So, you have to adjust the mysql export to use new line character(s) as line separator or you need to pre-process the dump to replace the `;` characters with new line.

Answer (score 2):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table) the syntax you should be using for `COPY` is:

```
COPY record_main FROM 'E:/CSV_files/record_main.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

As you can see, this is different from the command you were trying to run.  But `COPY` runs on the database server and requires a root account.  If you don't have one, you could also try using `\copy`:

```
\copy record_main(col1, col2, ...) FROM 'E:/CSV_files/record_main.csv'
    DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

**Update:**

@shadow correctly pointed out that you need to export your MySQL data into a CSV file whose lines are separated by a line separator, not semicolon.  But your Postgres copy syntax looks off, so maybe this answer will still help you.

Comment: use no quotes on \copy filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

I am doing wrong here by giving wrong line separator while creating the CSV from MySQL.

correct answer

```
INTO OUTFILE 'E:/CSV_files/record_main-new.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

There is no need to specify the line separator in the PostgreSQL automatically or default `"\n"`

From CSV to PostgreSQL import.

```
FROM 'E:/CSV_files/record_main-new.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER ',' NULL '\N'  CSV
```