# How to import CSV data to a Postgres table from a string?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I read this solution [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table) that seems to be fine if you want to load data from a file.

I download CSV data from an API endpoint and would like to avoid saving to a file if possible.

I have a NodeJS app that runs this query.

So, can I somehow pass not a file path, but, e.g. a string with the content to the query?

Something like this:

```
COPY zip_codes FROM 'john,doe,1982-02-01' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

Comment: probably from stdin?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from stdin` I suppose:

```
f=# create table aa(a text, b text, c date);
CREATE TABLE
f=# copy aa from stdin delimiter ',';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> john,doe,1982-02-01
>> \.
f=# select * from aa;
  a   |  b  |     c
------+-----+------------
 john | doe | 1982-02-01
(1 row)
```

**update**

as you reveal node.js, you are probably looking for https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams

here is some example:

js:

```
client.connect()
var copyFrom = require('pg-copy-streams').from;

var stream = client.query(copyFrom("COPY aa FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','"));
stream.write("john,doe,2017-02-01\n");
stream.end();
var queryresult = client.query('select * from aa', function(err,res) {
  console.log(err,res.rows);
  client.end();
});
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Vao\vatest>node t.js
null [ anonymous { a: 'john', b: 'doe', c: 2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z } ]
```

sql:

```
f=# select * from aa;
  a   |  b  |     c
------+-----+------------
 john | doe | 2017-02-01
(1 row)
```