# Import CSV datasheet to postgresql database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, csv

I have a csv file that contains 8 columns with more than 2000 rows. I need to import those data into the postgresql table.

I am using pgAdmin4 and I tried to import data to my postgresql table. But it gives me following error.

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "earliest_d" CONTEXT:
>
> COPY cors_data, line 1, column earliest_d: "earliest_d"

I think the reason is csv date fields are not recognize as a time stamp.

**earliest_d :** 2015 Oct 15 21:18

**latest_dat :** 2018 Feb 26 23:59

How can I make these csv date fields recongize by the postgresql application.

This is the SQL code generated in postgresql

```
-- Table: public.cors_data

-- DROP TABLE public.cors_data;

CREATE TABLE public.cors_data
(
    id character varying(80) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "interval" character varying(80) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lat character varying(120) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lon character varying(120) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    earliest_d timestamp without time zone,
    latest_dat timestamp without time zone,
    "Name" character varying(120) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "stnID" character varying(4) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT cors_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cors_data_interval_key UNIQUE ("interval"),
    CONSTRAINT cors_data_lat_key UNIQUE (lat),
    CONSTRAINT cors_data_lon_key UNIQUE (lon)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.cors_data
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I have referred some String to date conversion formats but nothing related to string date fromat in my csv.

[Example 1](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date)
[Example 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)

Comment: Perhaps in this format? 
`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: In my experience, You can import as text all data to another table, and then base on your data, you can update, format and insert into the right one.

Comment: Also, see... [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)