# How to load 3MB txt file line by line to a column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to load some test data to a table which has a column called `mytext` which has the type `TEXT`. I have a text format novel file which is 3MB in size. I am wondering if there is any easy and proper way to load the string line by line to the column `mytext` instead of looping it in a for loop from my client language. (each line per row).

Basically:

```sql
insert into table (column) values('a line of the text file')
```

### Edited

(1) My question is marked as a duplicate of loading csv formatted file. I need to edit it. I don't think it's a duplicate because I cannot use the solution mentioned in that post and my file is not a csv formatted file. It's simply just a novel, and I only need load data to one column too.

(2) I just want to load a novel data to a column and then I can test some LIKE, FTS features.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I have edited the question. You can have a look. I can not use the solution in that post and my file is not a csv file too. Thanks.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" Tim mentions does talk about CSV files, but the same COPY command also processes TEXT files. See Postgres documentation at
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html

Comment: @Belayer first, thanks for the comment. But I read that page and failed to find a way to achieve what I want. I did try COPY and \COPY command. But it failed to load the data line by line to one column. I mean each line per row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Make a copy first for the file)*

Here is a possibility

Load the file into vi

Issue the command to escape quotes

```
:1,$s/'/''/g
```

Issue the command to insert the insert statement at the start

```
:1,$s/^/insert into table values('/
```

Issue the command to insert the trailing stuff

```
:1,$s/$/');/
```

Write the file

```
:w
```

Quit vi

```
:q
```

Now you have the SQL required. Run that

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works. Btw missing `'` for `('` and `')`.

Comment: I feeling that all of that could be done by `sed` which is significant faster then `vi(m)` And `copy` command is faster also (for complex and bad formatted data `copy ... from program ...` could be used) PS: instead of `:w :q` `:x` could be used

Comment: @Abelisto yeah, `sed` can be used. I am not a `sed` user, and I may search how to do the same in `sed` later. Btw if you think `\copy` can be used in psql, can you provide a working command as a solution? I am glad to see a `\copy` solution. So far, I can not achieve what I want. Recall that I want to add each line per row to a column. `insert into table (column) values('a line of the text file')`.

Comment: @Abelisto hi, I posted a `sed` version suggested by you as an answer. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `vim` answer from Ed Heal, there is a `sed` version on MacOS:

```
sed "s/'/''/g" novel.txt > tmp1.sql

sed "s/^/insert into table (column) values('/" tmp1.sql > tmp2.sql

sed "s/$/');/" tmp2.sql > tmp3.sql

rm tmp1.sql tmp2.sql && mv -i tmp3.sql final.sql

psql -U user dbname < final.sql &> /dev/null
```

To combine all sed patterns to one line:

```
sed "s/'/''/g; s/^/insert into table (column) values('/; s/$/');/" novel.txt > final.sql
```