# Bulk insert from csv in postgres using golang without using for loop

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am new in Golang,

- I have csv file which have data looks like this

```
field1,field2
1.1,2
1.2,3
1.3,2
```

- i want to insert all csv data into db table using golang without using for loop .. i am using postgres database

also don't want to use sql raw query

i am using gorm ORM

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? What loop specifically are you trying to avoid? The loop reading the csv records, the loop inserting the individual records? Can you show what data structure you're using to represent the csv data in Go?

Comment: yes i don't want to loop through csv records

Comment: also don't want to make multiple insert records in for loop for each record of csv

Comment: Use batch insert.

Comment: can you able to provide any reference for the same ?

Comment: You can use [`COPY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table).

Comment: yes, but i have to use sql raw query for this

Comment: If not SQL, what do you want to use then? Are you using some ORM?

Comment: i want to do the same in golang .. please check edit

Comment: Standard golang executes raw SQL to insert records into a database.

Comment: as i said before i don't want to use raw SQL to insert recrods into a database

Comment: As mentioned, use [batch insert](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Batch-Insert), then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the CSV into a slice of typed structures [using an external library](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv), and then insert them all at once using GORM's [batch insert](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Batch-Insert).

Here is an example :

```golang
import (
    "os"

    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

// Entry defines both the CSV layout and database schema
type Entry struct {
    gorm.Model

    Field1 float64 `csv:"field1"`
    Field2 float64 `csv:"field2"`
}

func main() {
    // Open the CSV file for reading
    file, err := os.Open("data.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Parse CSV into a slice of typed data `[]Entry` (just like json.Unmarshal() does)
    // The builtin package `encoding/csv` does not support unmarshaling into a struct
    // so you need to use an external library to avoid writing for-loops.
    var entries []Entry
    err = gocsv.Unmarshal(file, &entries)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Open a postgres database connection using GORM
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open("host=localhost user=postgres password=dev dbname=foo port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Europe/Paris"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create `entries` table if not exists
    err = db.AutoMigrate(&Entry{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Save all the records at once in the database
    result := db.Create(entries)
    if result.Error != nil {
        panic(result.Error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid defining schema. I want to be able to export data and just re import without having to deal with schema in between.

Comment: This solution will consume a lot of memory.

Comment: This solution may be used with batches.

Comment: what about files with 10Gb size?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/) library for that:

```
    filename := "foo.csv"
    dbconn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer dbconn.Release()
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() { _ = f.Close() }()
    res, err := dbconn.Conn().PgConn().CopyFrom(context.Background(), f, "COPY csv_test FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(res.RowsAffected())
```

Comment: Not sure if its due to me using pgx/v4 but this doesn't compile. This part doesn't: ```dbconn.Conn().PgConn().CopyFrom```

Which pgx version should be used?

Comment: Try to use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749440/1109280

Comment: Thanks! That was my post, figured it out from you did.  I had to specifically use v1 of pgx instead of the latest v4.
Thanks @Pavlo Golub

Comment: Oh, I see. I use v4 for sure. But maybe I have misprint in my code example since I was extracting it from the working project. You may find it here: https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_timetable/blob/master/internal/pgengine/copy.go