# Postgres how to insert python dictionary from csv file?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I have a csv events.csv:

```
"PATIENT ID,PATIENT NAME,EVENT TYPE,EVENT VALUE,EVENT UNIT,EVENT TIME"
"1,Jane,HR,82,beats/minute,2021-07-07T02:27:00Z"
"1,Jane,RR,5,breaths/minute,2021-07-07T02:27:00Z"
```

Then I use python csv to read it:

```
import csv
with open(r'/Users/williaml/Downloads/events.csv') as csvfile: 
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',' ,quotechar=' ')
    for row in spamreader:            
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
{'"PATIENT ID': '"1', 'PATIENT NAME': 'Jane', 'EVENT TYPE': 'HR', 'EVENT VALUE': '82', 'EVENT UNIT': 'beats/minute', 'EVENT TIME"': '2021-07-07T02:27:00Z"'}

{'"PATIENT ID': '"1', 'PATIENT NAME': 'Jane', 'EVENT TYPE': 'RR', 'EVENT VALUE': '5', 'EVENT UNIT': 'breaths/minute', 'EVENT TIME"': '2021-07-07T02:27:00Z"'}
```

And I tried to insert these rows into database:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='patientdb',user='username',password='password',port='')
cur = conn.cursor()
import csv
with open(r'apps/patients/management/commands/events.csv') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',' ,quotechar=' ')
        for row in spamreader:
                cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES
  ({row['"PATIENT ID']},{row['EVENT TYPE']},{row['EVENT VALUE']},
   {row['EVENT UNIT']},{row['EVENT TIME"']})""")
```

Error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "1,HR,82,
   beats/minute,2021-07-07T02:27:00Z" does not exist
LINE 2:   ("1,HR,82,
           ^
```

However if I directly run the following sql in database command terminal it works:

```
INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES('1','HR','82','beats/minute','2021-07-07T02:27:00Z');
```

So I think it seems this part of code is incorrect:

```
cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES
      ({row['"PATIENT ID']},{row['EVENT TYPE']},{row['EVENT VALUE']},
       {row['EVENT UNIT']},{row['EVENT TIME"']})""")
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: Can you see anything in `{'"PATIENT ID': '"1',` which might be the reason for this. This is from your Output mentioned above which you are writing into db.

Comment: Why not to use [COPY](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/) ?

Comment: @balderman Not every column is needed.For example the PATIENT NAME is not needed can I still use copy ?

Comment: @William I think COPY knows how to handle this situation.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table#comment19538681_2987451) for how to use `copy` for specific columns.

Comment: Or more generally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table) question on SO.

Comment: Does the CSV file really have double quotes at the beginning and end of each line, and nowhere else? That would make each line a single field, which seems highly suspicious. That should be fixed upstream, if possible. And once you have sorted that out, please please please use [proper parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and not string formatting to pass values to SQL queries.

Comment: Second @TurePålsson comment. This starts with improperly formatted  `CSV` file. Fix that and the rest will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES ({1},{2},{3},{4},{5})"""
            .format(row['"PATIENT ID'][1:], row['EVENT TYPE'], row['EVENT VALUE'], row['EVENT UNIT'], row['EVENT TIME"'][:-1]))
```

So, this basically handles your extra quotes in the output dict which I have mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932434/postgres-how-to-insert-python-dictionary-from-csv-file#comment123620368_69932434) here which is causing this issue.

And, that's why

```
INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES('1','HR','82','beats/minute','2021-07-07T02:27:00Z');
```

passes on db terminal as you can see the difference between values inserted here in both ways.

**UPDATE**: Avoid using python's string formatting for queries as it can lead to wrong queries or vulnerable points for sql injection. See [parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to know the correct ways to do this, as Adrian have mentioned in comments below.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,after using your code,the error change to:psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "T02"
LINE 3:                    beats/minute,2021-07-07T02:27:00Z)

Comment: Do not use formatted strings to do this. Read this section of docs [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for correct way to do this. This should not be an accepted answer as it promotes bad coding.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver psycopg has nowhere mentioned explicitly that one should avoid using string formatting for queries. Also, they have used `.format` in the last code block in your mentioned [reference](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: That is the `format` provided by the  [psycopg2.sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) and is a method off `sql.SQL()`. It is an different thing, in particular because it does correct escaping. [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification) are just a form of string interpolation and are not suitable for building SQL queries.

Comment: Ok, my bad! But, I think the question is more about where OP was wrong and what a solution in his perspective would be. And I answered accordingly.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well I got turned around also as I referred to the `f string` the OP was using not the `str.format()` you used. Though the advice is the same as `str.format()` is yet another form of string interpolation.

Comment: To make the answer acceptable and to return the vote correct your example to use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

so one problem with CSV is `"` at the beginning and end of each line. The way you are interpreting it is causing it to become part of SQL expression.

```
           here 
LINE 2:   ("1,HR,82
```

And this is causing error, as it's not correctly closed`"` and actually it not intended for it to be in the generated SQL.