# Import data from one PostgresSQL database to another with constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have two databases and two apps. Initially they had same data. Later on, it has changed. Now I want to import some data from one database to another, but getting constraint restrictions. I thought I will just delete with sql command first from one, but then  I get constrain restrictions again with multiple other tables.

Tables that I want to move are like this **Manufacturers** has many **Systems** has many **Products**. So let's say *Apple* has *Iphone10* and *Iphone11* systems, and each of them has many parts. And they were used in other parts of application like **orders**.

Fields of the tables are not exactly the same.

So how could I delete data from those three tables in one database, and then import new data?

*The app is not in production

Answer (score 0):

To delete all data from a table or set of tables, you can use the truncate command.

```sql
TRUNCATE othertable CASCADE;
```

This specific command will cascade the truncate to tables with a foreign key restraint.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html

To import data, you can import from a CSV file

```sql
COPY zip_codes FROM '/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv);
```

[How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

Comment: #David Weber If I dont use cascade parameter it will remove rows only from the one table?

Comment: Yes, if you would like to remove from just certain tables just list them like this:
```TRUNCATE bigtable, fattable;```