# UTF8 error after pg_escape - Postgresql and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, utf-8

I have the following piece of code that reads a txt file and imports it to a postgresql db. I used pg_escape_string for all the text fields that could possibly contain special characters. Then I import it to the db. All successful. Later when I run a select query on the same data, I get a UTF8 error. I checked the hex for the error code and it is a character that is nowhere in my data. When I manually remove all the ' in the text file and run the import and select query again, all is working fine.

I have checked stack overflow for similar errors but could not find an answer that specifically works with the pg_escape_string and then get this error.

Any advice on how to run the import without manually removing ' and not getting the error please?

```php
$val9 = pg_escape_string(trim($meterArr[$row][9]));
$val10 = pg_escape_string(trim($meterArr[$row][10]));
INSERT INTO "Meters"("AgentCode", "BuildingNr", "MeterNr", "Premises", "SortCode", "PrevReading", "DatePrev", "ConsumptionPrev", "Variance", "MeterName", "CurrOccupant", "MeterType", "MeterNoR","currReading","lastReadingDate","percConsumption","dailyAvg")
                VALUES ('$val0', '$val1', '$val2', '$val3', '$val4', '$val5', '$val6', '$val7', '$val8', '$val9', '$val10', '$val11', '$val12','$val13','$val14','$val15','$val16')
                ON CONFLICT ("AgentCode","BuildingNr","MeterNr") DO UPDATE SET 
                "Premises" = '$val3',
                "SortCode" = '$val4',
                "PrevReading" = '$val5',
                "DatePrev" = '$val6',
                "ConsumptionPrev" = '$val7',
                "Variance" = '$val8',
                "MeterName" = '$val9',
                "CurrOccupant" = '$val10',
                "MeterType" = '$val11',
                "MeterNoR" = '$val12',
                "currReading" = '$val13',
                "lastReadingDate" = '$val14',
                "percConsumption"='$val15',
                "dailyAvg"='$val16';
```

This is just a snippet of the code.

I tried manual removal of special characters and I tried pg_escape_string. With manual removal everything is working but with pg_escape string it isn't.

Here is the output I get with urlencode(pg_escape_string($data[5])) with the problematic data.
Bergen%27%27s+Appliance+R

And then here is the actual data row from the txt file.
" 728"," 298"," 12"," 6998","00008","Bergen's Appliance R"," 62066.00"," 62066.00"," .00"," .00"," .00","2019- 1-25","25- 1-2019"," .00"," .00","N","N","N","N","E","N","N"," .00"," .00"," 0","N"," "," 1","Bergen's Appliance R ","Bergen's Appliance R","?? "," 0"

Comment: It makes little sense that the presence or absence of a `'` should actually make any difference in this regard. Could it be that those are not actually `'` - but something similarly looking, like an actual backtick ` or a ´? Problems with those would be to be expected, if your input text file is _not_ actually encoded in proper UTF-8.

Comment: I thought about this but I opened the txt file in VS Code and specifically searched for the apostrophe when I removed it.

Comment: So what does `pg_escape_string` return, for one of those problematic values? (Please apply something like `urlencode` when you make a debug output, so that we can see what actual byte values are in there, even for "invisible" characters.)

Comment: By the way -> Thats not valid PHP code.

Comment: The sql is only the query I posted. 

I will try to check with urlencode

Comment: Never used this function, I always found it much easier and clearer to use the function pg_query_params(). Clean PHP code, clean SQL, and no SQL injection: https://www.php.net/pg_query_params

Comment: Thank you. I will try pg_query_params() next. This is the output I get with urlecode with one of the problem values. Bergen%27%27s+Appliance+R.

Comment: "  728","     298","  12"," 6998","00008","Bergen's Appliance R","  62066.00","  62066.00","       .00","       .00","       .00","2019- 1-25","25- 1-2019","   .00","      .00","N","N","N","N","E","N","N","       .00","       .00","    0","N","        ","   1","Bergen's Appliance R                              ","Bergen's Appliance R","??                  ","     0"                                                                                                           This is what the string looks like in the txt file. I am working the 6th value.

Comment: It is so much easier to read code and data if you place it into the question.

Comment: All of these problems can be avoided if you simply **use placeholder values**. Also, instead of banging against a low-level driver, why not use PDO?

Comment: Why is URL encoding even used here in the first place? This is a database, not a URL, it does not apply. Anything that's inserted with URL encoding is effectively damaged and needs to be repaired.

Comment: PSA: If you have a CSV file you can [load that into Postgres directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table), skipping the escaping part entirely.

Comment: I am not using urlencode in my code. It was only used for debugging purposes. Please see previous comments. The program involved here is doing a lot of other stuff than just updating the db. It has a lot of calculations on the data and it is also sending emails with phpmailer. I can try PDO but since it is reading around 8 files and updating 8 tables, each file with around 120000 records, I was worried about the fact that PDO is slower than pg functions. It is already taking almost an hour to read these files and update the db and this db needs to be updated twice a day.