# Postgresql: CSV export with escaped linebreaks

Tags: postgresql, csv, export-to-csv

I exported some data from a postgresql database using (all) the instruction(s) posted here: [Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-postgres-sql-output-to-csv-file)

But some exported fields contains newlines (linebreaks), so I got a CSV file like:

```
header1;header2;header3
foobar;some value;other value
just another value;f*** value;value with
newline
nextvalue;nextvalue2;nextvalue3
```

How can I escape (or ignore) theese newline character(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line breaks are supported in CSV if the fields that contain them are enclosed in double quotes.

So if you had this in the middle of the file:

```
just another value;f*** value;"value with
newline"
```

it will be taken as 1 line of data spread on 2 lines with 3 fields and just work.

On the other hand, without the double quotes, it's an invalid CSV file (when it advertises 3 fields).

Although there's no formal specification for the CSV format, you may look at [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) for the rules that generally apply.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The problem was not the CSV-export but the import in Excel. Using libreoffice the file can be imported.