# Store Mysql Data in text file python

Tags: python

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="", passwd="", db="world")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

file = open('C:\\test\\File.txt', 'w')
file_content = file.write()


query = "SELECT * FROM city where name='kabul'"

cursor.execute(query, (file_content,))

mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

Here i'm storing the data in text file but error 
name `'file_content' is not defined`

Comment: You probably want to do `file.read()`, seeing as write expects a parameter of data to write. And you probably want `open('...', 'r')` and not `'w'` seeing as that overwrites the file, rather than opening it for data-reading.

Comment: Can you suggest me to store the database data in text file

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to store the response from the database in the file? If so you should write to the file and not just pass it as argument. If you're trying to read parameters for the query from the file then you have to use `file.read`. Although, the query has no paramters so it makes no sense as well. Please clarify.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270148/fastest-way-to-write-database-table-to-file-in-python.. posted code will not work anyways

Comment: I would suggest you re-write the entire thing and re-learn everything. You've missunderstood the basics of working with files and working with database calls. You've flipped the things around completely. So start over by reading and writing files, get a hang for it. Re-learn simple database inputs and outputs, how to store and how to fetch results. Once you're comfortable with these two, merge them together into your solution.

Comment: @GowthamMuruvanda I have posted an answer, kindly check. But still, as others suggest, you should try and solve these minor issues yourself rather than looking for help. Have fun coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want fetch all the rows from MySQL and then further write the `row-data` in the file.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="", passwd="", db="world")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

file_to_use = open('C:\\test\\File.txt', 'w+')

query = "SELECT * FROM city where name='kabul'"

cursor.execute(query)
row_data = cursor.fetchone()
while row_data is not None:
    file_to_use.write(str(row_data))
    file_to_use.write("\n")
    row_data = cursor.fetchone()
file_to_use.close()
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

This will write the fetched `tuple` which is `row_data` into the text file with each row in a new line.

Comment: Thanks. but i'm getting this error

>>> row_data = cursor.fetchone()
>>> while row_data is not None:
...     file.write(str(row_data))
...     file.write("\n")
...     row_data = cursor.fetchone()
... file.close()
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    file.close()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Well, there must be an error in your code where `file.close()` is not written the way it is intended to. Also, I'd ask you to change the variable name from `file` to something  like `new_file` or `file_to_use`