# PostgreSQL 8.4 COPY command parse error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm novice in PostgreSQL 8.4, I'm trying to export csv files from temporary tables.

As I wrote

```
SET client_encoding TO 'SJIS';
\copy temp_table TO 'temp_table.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

However, this code returns error like

`\copy: parse error at ";"`

Please help me...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) the correct syntax is

```
COPY { table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ] | ( query ) }
    TO { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDOUT }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

With that, your `COPY` statement should look like below, remove the `\` and `WITH`

```
SET client_encoding TO 'SJIS';
copy temp_table TO 'temp_table.csv' CSV HEADER;
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

(OR) Removing the `;` as suggested by @IMSoP

```
\copy temp_table TO 'temp_table.csv' WITH HEADER
```

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` meta-command; `COPY` is an SQL statement. They are related, but different.

Comment: Thank you so much! I resolved this problem to remove the ";".

Answer (score 1):

`\copy` is an internal "meta-command" of [the `psql` command-line client](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#copy) ([8.4-specific documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-psql.html#copy)), not an SQL statement.

It is designed to look very similar to an SQL `COPY` statement, but doesn't require (or accept) a terminating `;`, since all meta-commands are terminated by a newline or `\` (which is taken as the start of a new meta-command).

So you should be able to simply remove the character it's complaining about:

```
SET client_encoding TO 'SJIS';
\copy temp_table TO 'temp_table.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

See also [this answer about `COPY` and `\copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-postgres-sql-output-to-csv-file/1517692#1517692).

Comment: You have given a nice answer in that link. Given a +1 there. Good read. As well I have edited my answer based on your suggestion and removed `;`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I do in this way and I can export csv files. And the link is very nice. I should learn about the difference between `COPY` and `\copy`. I confused about that.

Comment: @IMSoP , if i want to call these 3 lines from a shell script then how to call it ? 
back slash before copy command is creating error from shell script.