# How to export query results directly to a local CSV file from RubyMine

Tags: postgresql, rubymine

I am using RubyMine 6.3.3 Database Console window to run queries and export them to CSV

This involves 3 steps

Step 1. Run the query, wait quite some time to get results in a Visual way

[image: Run the query to get results in a Visual way]

Step 2. Click on the "File Icon" and select "Save All To File"

[image: Click on the "File Icon" and select "Save All To File]

Step 3: Wait again the same time of the step 1 to export it to CSV

[image]

I have checked RubyMine forums, the settings, whithout any success.

I also found this question on how to [save (postgres) sql output to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-postgres-sql-output-to-csv-file)

The answer to that question mentions this command

> Copy (Select * From foo) To '/tmp/test.csv' With CSV;

but by using that approach the file is save on the server which I dont have direct access to.

**Is there a way to run the query and get the results directly into a local CSV file, without getting the visual results**

Comment: Can you connect to the database from [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I actually made a dumb mistake when configuring pgadmin and now I can connnect, but still this feature is planed. see my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not yet implemented and is already and feature that has been requested to JetBrains and is reported in this links

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-454

http://track.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-442#tab=Linked Issues

So people interested in tracking this and update this answer please do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to do what you ask: [image]

Answer (score 1):

This feature is working in RubyMine 8

On the right side of your query result you can select the export type.

[image]

Refresh/reload your query

[image]

Select the lines you want to export, e.g. cmd + a to select all

copy the values with cmd + c

open a new textfile and paste the data with cmd + v

Comment: Or, if you want to export the whole table/result at once, there is a button "Dump data to file"

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect with `psql` use the `\copy` command to save the file at the client.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: @clodoado thanks for the answer, this helps me solve the original problem, but this answer is not related to the original question