# PostgreSQL query output as a excel file

Tags: excel, postgresql, export, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I want to save the result of a psql query as an Excel file. 
ie, I have a table named company with 5 column. I want to execute the query,

```
SELECT column_1,
       column_2,
     FROM company;
```

And I just want to save the result of this query as a Excel file. Is it possible in PostgreSQL? If yes then please explain it.

Thank you......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use csv to save your data and open/work with them in Excel. Syntax would be something like:

```
Copy (SELECT column_1,
             column_2,
      FROM company; 
     ) 
To '/tmp/test.csv' With CSV;
```

This query would run on server. You could also make usage of `\query` which is running on your client and saving the data locally. See also another [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file)