# How to export a table with particular condition and then to export excel in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to export this table to Excel using the above condition.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = 'condition'
```

Comment: If `column_name` be the name of an actual column, then you should use single quotes: `WHERE column_name = 'condition'`

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987226/postgresql-query-output-as-a-excel-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL query output as a excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987226/postgresql-query-output-as-a-excel-file)