# Export postgres table based on rails relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a user table that I can easily export with postgres by doing

```
\copy users to 'tmp/users2015.csv' csv header
```

My users has_many questions, and I'm wondering if there's a way I can export just the users who have asked a question. The problem is here's no column in my users table that represents the number of questions a user has asked, so I don't think I can do this. Is there any possible way or a different approach? I really care about just knowing how many users have asked questions, so I could also export my questions table, and possibly filter out questions that have been asked by the same user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the same select query that the has_many relationship uses and use that to write to a file.

```
Copy (Select * From users where <some condition>) To '/tmp/test.csv' With CSV
```

See [Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your should export in additional to the `user` table a table which has a `belongs_to` field, for example of `question` table, to 'tmp/question2015.csv' CSV.