# Absolute path is treated as a relative path

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I'm trying to export table's data into a file with csv format.

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM mailing.value) TO 'C:\\Users\\asd\\Desktop\\value.csv' (format csv);
```

But I got with

> ERROR: relative path not allowed for COPY to file

How can I fix that?

Comment: not that I have any experience with this but you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file

Comment: @MaheshKava I've tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: Searching for the error message can be handy. In this case I think maybe we need to add a `HINT` message in the error...

Comment: Odd, I think the real issue is that we're detecting that as a relative path. Though more HINTs in those COPY errors in general would be good.