# Can I use \copy command into a function of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv

I am trying to create this statement into a function:

```
\copy aux("nombre") TO '/home/david/lugares.csv' delimiters ';';
```

So I do the next:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crearcsv()
      RETURNS void AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE STATEMENT TEXT; 
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'CREAR CSV';
        STATEMENT:= '\copy aux ("nombre") TO ''/home/david/lugares.csv'' delimiters '';'';';    
        RAISE NOTICE '%',STATEMENT;
        EXECUTE STATEMENT;
    END;$BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
```

But I get the next when I call to the function:

> NOTICE: \copy aux ("nombre") TO '/home/david/lugares.csv' delimiters ';';
>   ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
>   LINE 1: \copy aux ("nombre") TO '/home/david/lugares.csv' delimiters...
>   ^
>   QUERY: \copy aux ("nombre") TO '/home/david/lugares.csv' delimiters ';';
>   CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function crearcsv() line 7 at EXECUTE statement**

This statement works fine in PSQL console

Any help?

Comment: That's because `\copy` is a [psql command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) that does more or less what the [sql command copy does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html) - with the most important difference that `\copy` uses files on the filesystem of the computer running psql, and `copy` uses files on the server's filesystem. So, they are highly similar but not identical, and you cannot use \copy in a function as it's not an sql command.

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` command and can **only** be executed from within `psql`. It is **not** a general SQL statement.

Comment: Then, how can I do this function?

Comment: @user3733164 You can't. There's no way to read or write files on the client via a pl/pgsql function

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change `\copy` in `copy`. `COPY` is the "sql variant" of `\copy`, works in a database function, the syntax is identical but has some differences which can be relevant for you:

> COPY is the Postgres method of data-loading. Postgres's COPY comes in
>   two separate variants, COPY and \COPY: COPY is server based, \COPY is
>   client based.
>
> COPY will be run by the PostgreSQL backend (user "postgres"). The
>   backend user requires permissions to read & write to the data file in
>   order to copy from/to it. You need to use an absolute pathname with
>   COPY. \COPY on the other hand, runs under the current $USER, and with
>   that users environment. And \COPY can handle relative pathnames. The
>   psql \COPY is accordingly much easier to use if it handles what you
>   need.
>
> With either of these you'll also need to have insert/update or select
>   permission on the table in order to COPY to or from it.

From https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY

The main difference is that `COPY` will write the output file on the file system where the postgres server is running, not on the server where you execute `COPY`. This will be the same, if you have a postgres server running on localhost, but can be big problem by more complex scenarios.

See also the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html

and this answer: [Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file/1517692#1517692)

Comment: The drawback of this is that `copy` can only be used by a superuser in Postgres as it will write files on the server.

Comment: As well as a_horse_with_no_name says, I can't use COPY because it needs to be used by a superuser. Sorry because of I didnt mentioned it

Comment: File system IO operations are generally uncomfortable via database functions (but not impossible: in depends on your scenario). You can try with plpython or plperl, but you could have similar problems as with plpgsql. Try with a shell script which execute psql.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better writing a Python script that connects to the DB and runs the COPY command. Psycopg2 is the best adapter for this.