# Exporting SQL Query to a local text file

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is for an approach that WRITES to a local file.

I am using SQL WorkBench and I'm connected to an AWS Redshift instance (which uses postgresql).  I would like to run the query and have data exported from AWS Redshift to a local csv or text file.  I have tried:

```
SELECT  transaction_date ,
    Variable 1 ,
    Variable 2 ,
    Variable 3 ,
    Variable 4 ,
    Variable 5 
From xyz
into OUTFILE 'C:/filename.csv'
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "'C:/filename.csv'"
  Position: 148

into OUTFILE 'C:/filename.csv'
```

Comment: why not use PostgreSQL Web GUI eg SIDU to export to a csv

Comment: Is there not a way to export to csv directly in the query?

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file

Comment: That is for an approach that runs entirely on the remote server.

Comment: @ZJAY - the link provided by @SIDU also covers exporting to local client using `psql` command-line, have you looked at that.. ?

Comment: I get this error when trying that:  An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
\copy (

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1

\copy (
^

Comment: Are you writing your query correctly here? There is no `FROM` clause. If those are scalars, where are the functions they derive from?

Comment: Yes, I truncated the query to get to the meat of the problem: into Outfile.

Comment: Remove the \ (backslash) in front of [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-copy.html) which is a command line psql directive not SQL command.

Comment: I did this - got this error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 5

Comment: copy(
SELECT  variable 1 ,
        variable 2 ,
        variable 3 ,