# How to save PostgreSQL output to text file

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-copy

I've struggled with other StackOverflow responses. I would like to save the output of a query to a local text file - it doesn't really matter where the text file is located as long as it is on my local machine.

Code I am using:

```
\COPY (
select month,count(*) as distinct_Count_month 
from
(
select UNIQUE_MEM_ID,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
FROM yi_fourmpanel.card_panel WHERE COBRAND_ID = '10006164'
group by UNIQUE_MEM_ID,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')
) a
group by month) TO 'mycsv.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

Error with this code is:

```
<!-- language: none -->

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
\COPY (

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1

\COPY (
^

Execution time: 0.08s
(Statement 1 of 2 finished)

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select month,count(*) as distinct_Count_month 
from
(
select UNIQUE_MEM_ID,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
FROM yi_fourmpanel.card_panel...

ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 260

group by month) TO 'mycsv.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
              ^

Execution time: 0.08s
(Statement 2 of 2 finished)

2 statements failed.
Script execution finished
Total script execution time: 0.16s
```

Comment: `\copy` (not `\COPY`)  is a `psql` command, not a regular SQL statement and it will **only** work with the command line client `psql` The error message you are showing doesn't look like you are using `psql`, so `\copy` won't work there. You need to use whatever "export" feature your SQL client is offering.

Comment: I'm using SQL Workbench - any idea?

Comment: You can use WbExport for that: http://sql-workbench.net/manual/command-export.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

1.For **server COPY** remove `\` and run in `psql` following:

```
COPY (
WITH data(val1, val2) AS ( VALUES
  ('v1', 'v2')
)
SELECT *
FROM data
) TO 'yourServerPath/output.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

`cat yourServerPath/output.csv` :

```
val1,val2
v1,v2
```

2.For **client COPY**:

```
psql -h host -U user -d database -c "\copy \
( \
  WITH data(val1, val2) AS ( VALUES \
    (1, 2) \
) \
SELECT * FROM data) TO 'yourClientPath/output.csv' CSV HEADER;"
```

`cat yourClientPath/output.csv`:

```
val1,val2
1,2
```

#### UPDATED

As for example provided, on your client machine in terminal you need to run following script with **absolute** path to your `mycsv.csv` :

```
psql -h host -U username -d db -c "\COPY ( \
select month,count(*) as distinct_Count_month \
from \
  ( \
    select UNIQUE_MEM_ID,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month \
    FROM yi_fourmpanel.card_panel WHERE COBRAND_ID = '10006164' \
    group by UNIQUE_MEM_ID,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') \
  ) a \
group by month) TO 'path/mycsv.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;"
```

Comment: That creates the file on the **server**, ZJAY wants the file locally.

Comment: changed @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I don't think I follow - would you mind editing my code with your changes or be a bit more explicit what I should change as part of my code.  Thanks for the consideration and help.