# Copy columns from 2 table to create a CSV File (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL and I want to join them with where condition. After I joined them, I want to convert to CSV file using copy function. Is it possible to join and generate the CSV file using COPY function? Or is it have another method?

Comment: This is possible, but you did not show us the query or table structure, so we can't help you.

Comment: `copy from (select col1, col2, from t1 join t2 on ... where ...) to ...`. See the examples in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html#AEN77768

Comment: This has the answer that you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible and very easy.

Let's suppose we have two tables, `merchant_position` and `merchant_timeline`. In `(mp_sc_id, mp_merchant_id, mp_rank, mp_tier, mp_updated_at)`, all these fields are from the `merchant_position` table but (`mt_name`) is in `merchant_timeline table` and foreign key is `mt_id` and `mp_merchant_id`.

```
\copy (select mp_sc_id, mp_merchant_id, mp_rank, mp_tier, mp_updated_at, mt_name from merchant_position INNER JOIN merchant_timeline ON mt_id = mp_merchant_id) TO '/Users/Desktop/mercahnt_rank.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```