# Export PSQL table to CSV file using cmd line args

Tags: sql, bash, psql

I am attempting to export my PSQL table to a CSV file. I have read many tips online, such as [Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file?rq=1)

From these posts I have been able to figure out

```
\copy (Select * From foo) To '/tmp/test.csv' With CSV
```

However I do not want to specify the path, I would like the user to be able to enter it via the export shell script. Is it possible to pass args to a .sql script from a .sh script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution.

In my bash script I used something similar to the following

```
psql $1 -c "\copy (SELECT * FROM users) TO '"$2"'" DELIMINTER ',' CSV HEADER"
```

This code copies the user table from the database specified by the first argument and exports it to a csv file located at the second arguement