# How to save Amazon Redshift output to local CSV through SQL Workbench?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, export-to-csv, sql-workbench-j

I am writing psql through Amazon Redshift and now I am trying to save the output as CSV through PSQL query, on SQL Workbench
The reason I am planning to do this through query instead of using `select` clause and then right click to save the output as csv, is because there are large amount of data, I found that if I generate the output into a temp table, it's much much faster than using `select` to display all the output. Therefore, I am thinking whether saving to local CSV can be faster too.

I have tried the top solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file), however, it doesn't work on Amazon Redshift, When I am using `Copy (SELECT col1, col2 FROM my_table) TO '[my local csv path]' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';`, or tried `\Copy`, it kept showing me

> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "("

or

> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "\"

Then I have checked [Amazon Redshift query tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_commands.html), didn't find any clause that could save the output to local CSV. It seems that `COPY` is to copy data from an Amazon data source to Redshift, `UNLOAD` is to save data to s3, but I just want to save the data on my local machine.

So, is there any way to save the **Redshift output** to my **local CSV**  but with SQL Workbench?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running any one of the following in the Workbench

```
WbExport -type=text
         -file='C:\Downloads\myData.txt'
         -delimiter='\t'
         -decimal=','
         -dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd';
select a, b ,c from myTable;

WbExport -type=text
     -file='C:\Downloads\myQuery.txt'
     -delimiter='\t'
     -header=true
     -tableWhere="WHERE a is not null and date between 11/11/11 and 22/22/22"
     -sourcetable=mytable;
```

Comment: I did a minor change in your solution and finally it works for me. Could you add `;` after `-dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'`? Otherwise it won't work. Thank you very much!

Comment: I used the first solution you provided, but get the following error: "ERROR [42601] [Amazon][Amazon Redshift] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: [SQLState 42601] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WbExport"
LINE 1: WbExport -type=text ^". Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: @CathyQian Can you put it in one line and see if the error message is improved rr if you can post your short form query,

Answer (score 12):

Yes there is, try this out.

```
PGPASSWORD=<password> psql -h <host> -d <db> -U <user> -p 5439-a -c "select * from <table>" -F '<delimiter>' -o temp.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My data is temp table, and I am working on SQL WorkBench. So using terminal may not work in this case. Just added that I am using `SQL WorkBench` in the question. Is there any method to write psql query through SQL WorkBench and save the output to local CSV?

Comment: I am no expert in tool usage, but I see once you got result set in workbench,  you can save data using menu option  Data -> Save Data As -> ?, Btw, redshift doesn't support all postgres way of loading and unloading

Comment: I could not use "save as" through work bench was because `select` clause can be running forever there, but saving to a file can be much faster.... that's why I am asking for any query available~ Anyway, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is about Workbench but if you are willing to go to command line on linux possibly this is a solution, it's working nicely for us

```
#!/bin/zsh 
#we are assuming you are not appending to each file and you don't need header
out_put='/tmp/output.csv'
#be very careful here rm -rf is very dangerous 
rm -rf $out_put

PGPASSWORD='YOUR_PASSWORD' psql -h YOUR_STUFF-cluster-1.YOUR_STUFF.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -p YOUR_PORT_NUMBER -d YOUR_DATABASE -U YOUR_USER_NAME -A -t -c "select * from SOME_TABLE limit 10" -F ',' -o $out_put


echo "your file is ready" $out_put
```