# How do I prevent PSQL from outputting the number of rows?

Tags: amazon-redshift, psql

Currently I can almost get a CSV from psql by simply running

```
psql -A -t -F'\t' -c "SELECT ...;" > myfile.csv
```

However it returns the number of rows at the end of the file. I can fix his with `head -n -1`

```
psql -A -t -F'\t' | head -n -1 | -c "SELECT ...;"
```

But with very large files seems like overkill. Is here a flag in psql where I can turn off number of records returned?

Comment: Probably `--pset="footer=off" ` (I can not test).

Comment: This works, Please post this as answer

Comment: Oh, there are better answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file) :)

Comment: None of that works on redshift! Your answer is the better one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a number of common ways to get a CSV from PostrgeSQL (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file)). However not all of these ways are appropriate when working with Redshift, partly because Amazon Redshift is based on Postgres 8.0.2.

One can try to use `--pset="footer=off"` option to prevent `psql` from outputting the number of rows. Also, please consult  [8.0.26 psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/app-psql.html).