# Unexpected type error when export data from table to text file

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am trying to export the data from the table to txt file. I have code as follows

```
class Optimization_goolge(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbname = ""
        self.usr_name = ""
        self.usr_pass = ""
        self.con = ""
        self.cur = ""
        self.openTime=""

    def vT(self, x, y, z, openTime):
        try:
            con_string="dbname = '%s' user = '%s' password ='%s' host = 'localhost'"%(x,y,z)
            con = psycopg2.connect(con_string)
            con.set_isolation_level(0)
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute(("""COPY (select source, target, sum(cost)/1000 as cost from distance_matrix where source != 88888888 and target
             != 88888888 group by source, target order by source) TO '%s\\vrp_distance.txt'""") % (os.getcwd()))
            con.commit()
```

But I am getting error

```
error vT Function could not open file "D:\working_copy\vrp_distance.txt" for writing: No such file or directory

Error optimizeFxn_google arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QMessageBox.warning(QWidget, QString, QString, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Optimization_goolge'
  QMessageBox.warning(QWidget, QString, QString, int, int, int button2=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Optimization_goolge'
  QMessageBox.warning(QWidget, QString, QString, QString, QString button1Text=QString(), QString button2Text=QString(), int defaultButtonNumber=0, int escapeButtonNumber=-1): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Optimization_goolge'
```

Comment: As it comes from `getcwd()` I guess the directory exists. Do you have writing permissions? Moreover, you should use `os.path.join()` to join paths instead of your manual way. You can additionally use `.format()` to increase readability.

Comment: @mikuszefski yes directory and file do exist. how to use format(). can you give me an example

Comment: have a look in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filepath = os.path.join(dir_path, 'vrp_distance.txt')

sql_statement = ("COPY (select source, target, sum(cost)/1000" 
" as cost from distance_matrix where source != 88888888 and target"
" != 88888888 group by source, target order by source) TO"
" '{}'".format(filepath))
```

Sidenotes to consider (not in original question):

- why not separate responsibilities to extract information and write it to file - you will knwo for sure which part fails
- `OptimizationGoolge`, by convention
- if you init a class with null strings, something is wrong in class design
- rename `vT` to somehting meaningful

You have to check too:

```
assert os.path.exists('D:/working_copy/vrp_distance.txt') 
assert os.path.exists('D:/working_copy')
```

Also check [Save PL/pgSQL output from PostgreSQL to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file). If you do not have a writing permission, all of the above is fruitless.

Comment: Yes your code could remove all the error which brings back to my same error  error vT Function could not open file "D:\working_copy\vrp_distance.txt" for writing: No such file or directory

Comment: result of filepath is D:\working_copy\vrp_distance.txt

Comment: And the asserts pass? @user1687891

Comment: I think the multiline string needs a backslash line continuation.

Comment: ... by convention you refer to PEP8?

Comment: @mikuszafski, if parts are in parenthesis, it does not

Comment: PEP8 suggests you CapWords for class names

Comment: my database is in different server and my code is local

Comment: that my be a reason - this code attempts to write to remote server. if you have a path relative from the server, you can supply that (eg on a local networ, otherwise the solution is to get the select result and save it locally.