# Export CSV file from redshift to local with appropriate variable types

Tags: python, sql, database, csv, amazon-redshift

I am trying to directly export a table from redshift to my local computer. I am successful in getting data from redshift however it doesn't differentiate any of the data. When I do pandas.dtypes they all come out as objects and not various data types such as string or date timestamps. I would also like to add the headers of the columns straight from the export.

I've successfully exported to my local using PSQL commands from my terminal to access the redshift.

```
psql -h omaha-prod-cluster.example.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -d prod -U <username> -p 5439 -A -t -c "select * from l2_survey.survey_customerinsight" -F ',' -o Downloads/survey_customerInsights.csv
```

I am then running the panda command to read the kinds of data types

```py
data.dtypes()
```

and it is returning every column with the data type of object. It also doesn't give me the headers of the columns with the psql command above

Comment: Look into Postgres' [`COPY...TO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517692/1422451) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with your command where you are `explicitly` asking the `export` `command` to skip the column names by supplying the argument `-t`, which tells the command to just export `tuples` without `column` names. Just change it like below and it will provide you the `header`.

```
psql -h <host-values>.redshift.amazonaws.com -U <user> -d <database> -p 5439 -c "select * from your_schema.your_table" > out.txt
```

Hope it helps you.