# Mysql cli stream to file

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to stream the output of a query in mysql to a file?

Of course I can do `mysql -e "select id from huge_table" > my_file.txt`

But that seems to wait to end the query before outputting the content to the file, which would be of course bad at memory level.

Can the query be streamed as the results are fetch.

In postgres there is the `\copy` [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file) which does precisely this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [--quick](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_quick)

> This option is useful for dumping large tables. It forces mysqldump to retrieve rows for a table from the server a row at a time rather than retrieving the entire row set and buffering it in memory before writing it out.