# Postgres replace null values by an empty string

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>;
```

I do not know the fields in the table, hence I use the wildcard '*' in the query.
How can I replace null values by an empty string and how do I cast all columns to a string.

Comment: Use `coalesce(column, '')`

Comment: You cannot do it without knowing the column names.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need Dynamic SQL here then and build your query by querying the table's columns.

Comment: Let the application that sends this query to the database, handle the nulls.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Getting the column names is easy. You can get then from `information_schama.columns` or just get list run the query `select * from <table_name> limit 0;` in psql or any database management tool.

Answer (score 1):

To replace `NULL` values with an empty string, use `COALESCE(column_name, '')`. You'll need to know the column name and do this for each column name.

To convert a column into text, you can use `column_name::TEXT` or `CAST(column_name AS TEXT)`. You'll also need to know the column names.

If you just want something quick and dirty that achieves something close to your goal, you can convert the whole row tuple into text:

```sql
SELECT my_table::TEXT FROM my_table
```

In this case, you'll get parentheses around the row which each value separated by a column. It's generally not ideal, and you'll lose the column name information, but could be handy if you want a quick and simple text search for example. (I'm sure there are better solutions to that particular problem.)

Another option, which may depend on the client you're using, is to use [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) (or `psql`'s `\copy`) and export your data in CSV format to the standard output or to a file. There are more details on this in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517692/372643).

The default CSV value for `NULL` is the empty string, but [you could have quotes or something else using `WITH NULL AS ...`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211723/2129)

---

You could also use some dynamic PL/pgSQL to create your query. Building the query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT '
       || string_agg('COALESCE('
                     || attname::TEXT
                     || '::TEXT, '''')' , ',' ORDER BY attnum)
       || ' FROM my_table'
    INTO q
    FROM pg_attribute WHERE  attrelid = 'my_table'::regclass
     AND attnum > 0 AND NOT attisdropped;
```

It's then a problem regarding how you want to return those results (since you'd may to know the columns in advance for using record or row types).

Since you're only interested in text, you might as well return each row as a `TEXT` array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() RETURNS SETOF TEXT[]
AS $$
DECLARE
    q TEXT;
    r TEXT[];
BEGIN
    SELECT 'SELECT ARRAY['
           || string_agg('COALESCE('
                         || attname::TEXT
                         || '::TEXT, '''')' , ',' ORDER BY attnum)
           || '] FROM my_table'
        INTO q
        FROM pg_attribute WHERE  attrelid = 'my_table'::regclass
         AND attnum > 0 AND NOT attisdropped;
    FOR r IN EXECUTE q
    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT my_function();
```