# How to export table data to file

Tags: postgresql

I would like to export a single Postgres table's data into a .csv file. Can anyone give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export Postgres table to CSV file with headings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In psql:

```
\copy tablename to 'filename' csv;
```

Comment: Just for completeness - how would someone import this on the other end?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgres-table

Comment: And where this file is stored?, cuz I want to export it in my localhost server.

Comment: When I try to do this it says "permission denied" does the file already need to exist? or what is going on here

Answer (score 67):

First, log into the PostgreSQL console via the command line with the `psql` command.

**To export:**

```
\connect database_name;
\copy my_table TO 'my_table.csv' CSV;
\q
```

**To import:**

```
\connect database_name;
\copy my_table FROM 'my_table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
\q
```

Done!

---

**Or, from a shell script!**

```
export PGPASSWORD=dbpass
psql --dbname=mydb --username=dbuser --host=127.0.0.1 -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM widget) TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" > export.csv
```

*Bonus Advice*
Use [pgcli](https://www.pgcli.com/), it's way better than psql

Comment: Plus 1 for pointing to pgcli, that is a cool and useful command line client

Comment: The shell script was a savior.

Answer (score 12):

When logged into psql:

```
COPY tablename TO 'filename';
```

For more details, see this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: And that will copy the data to a server-accessible file. Which may or may not be the goal. For a client-side copy (inside `psql`) use `\copy`.

Comment: also you have to be a superuser to use `COPY`, but not to use `\copy`