# Unable to create query COPY PostgreSQL PQSQL driver

Tags: qt, postgresql, csv

Well the thing is that when the program execute the query to copy a table to a file .CSV. Qt show me the next error.

> "ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
>   LINE 1: EXECUTE

Here are the code of the export action:

```
QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("copy inventory to './inventory.csv'");
if(qry.exec()){
    qDebug()<<"Succes";
}else{
    qDebug()<<qry.lastError().text();
}
```

The version of qt is 5.4, used postgresql 9.3 and driver PQSQL working fine just can execute another's query very well like select.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use `COPY` like any other query. You need to use a driver-specific function that understands the COPY protocol.

Comment: Friend, how i do that?. I mean the qpsql-driver don't have that funcionality?

Comment: Another idea behave, is use psql execute with qt?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you're using Qt's SQL interface and its PostgreSQL driver.

While Qt's PostgreSQL driver is built on top of PostgreSQL's standard client library `libpq`, as far as I can tell it does not offer support for lots of the functionality of `libpq`. In particular, there appears to be no way to access support for the `COPY` protocol, nor for `LISTEN`ing for asynchronous notifications.

You will have to:

- `libpq` directly to `COPY ... FROM STDIN`
- or use regular `INSERT` statements via Qt; or
- Transfer the CSV input to the server, then use `COPY ... FROM '/path/on/server'` to read the input from a file on the server that the PostgreSQL database is running on, readable by the user the PostgreSQL database runs as.

(You could also submit a patch to Qt to add support for the `COPY` protocol,  which shouldn't be too hard to implement, but is perhaps not the best choice if you're asking this.)

Comment: @MRlinux Qt is just a C++ framework. `libpq` is a C library, and can be used directly in C++ code. You just use `libpq`'s API's directly, per the PostgreSQL manual.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `COPY` needs superuser rights . Do not confuse with `\COPY` of
   PostgreSQL
2. `COPY TO` requires absolute path to the output file. If 1st point is
   considered, try removing the `./` in your output file name
3. You can refer to related posts:
   [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings)
   and
   [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517635/save-pl-pgsql-output-from-postgresql-to-a-csv-file)