# Read a PostgreSQL local file into R in chunks and export to .csv

Tags: r, sqldf, rpostgresql, rsqlite

I have a local file in `PostgreSQL` format that I would like to read into R into chunks and export it as `.csv`.

I know this might be a simple question but I'm not at all familiar with `PostgreSQL` or `SQL`. I've tried different things using R libraries like `RPostgreSQL`, `RSQLite` and `sqldf` but I couldn't get my head around this.

Comment: What is the purpose of breaking the data into chunks?

Comment: What is "`PostgreSQL` format"? I've never heard of that, and I've used PostgreSQL a lot.

Comment: @DanBracuk, the file size is 18GB so I would like to do this task in chunks to go around the memory limitations in R.

Comment: @bgoldst I guess this gives you an idea of how unfamiliar I am with PostgreSQL. The file I have is zipped with name "gps_PostgreSQL.rar". The file name is "gps_p.backup"

Comment: Are you updating an existing file or creating a very large one from scratch?

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm creating one from scratch.

Comment: You don't need to do it in chunks.  You can just use the PostgreSQL `copy` command to write it directly to a csv file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings

Answer (score 1):

If your final goal is to create a csv file, you can do it directly using PostgreSQL.

You can run something similar to this:
COPY my_table TO 'C:\my_table.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Sorry if I misunderstood your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to programmatically create a very large .csv file from scratch and populate it from data in a database?  I would use this approach.

Step 1 - isolate the database data into a single table with an auto incrementing primary key field.  Whether you always use the same table or create and drop one each time depends on the possibility of concurrent use of the program.

Step 2 - create the .csv file with your programming code.  It can either be empty, or have column headers, depending on whether or not you need column headers.

Step 3 - get the minimum and maximum primary key values from your table.

Step 4 - set up a loop in your programming code using the values from Step 3.  Inside the loop:

- query the table to get x rows
- append those rows to your file
- increment the variables that control your loop

Step 5 - Do whatever you have to do with the file.  Don't try to read it with your programming code.

Comment: thank you for your answer, where you have laid out the logic of the process. I would be grateful if you or someone could develop this in `R` code.

regarding step 1: I've seen some tutorial on how to write a `data.frame` into a SQL database, but I couldn't find how to do write the my local file into a SQL database.

Comment: It won't be me.  I'm a ColdFusion programmer who read the question because of the sql tag.  The approach I suggest should work with any language and database engine.  Another approach I recommend is to do one thing at a time.  Finally, during development, work with small amounts of data.