# Unload data from postgres to s3

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to unload a table data from postgres database into amazon s3.

I'm aware that redshift has a option of unload into s3 - Since redshift is a postgres database, I tried using the same command in my postgres database but was unsuccesful.

Can someone help me with unloading table data from postgres into s3 periodically ?

Comment: `COPY ... TO PROGRAM`

Comment: and if you are not superuser, just split to two steps: `copy to file` and `aws s3 cp file to bucket`

Answer (score 6):

Redshift is based on a PostgreSQL clone but there's not 1-1 feature correspondence. If you want to load data from a PostgreSQL DB to Redshift, through S3, you should:

1. Unload your data from PostgreSQL to a CSV file. To do that use the copy command of psql. See also this Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings).
2. Copy the CSV file on S3. There are different ways to do that but check the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)
3. Use the [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command to load the data from S3 to Redshift

Answer (score 2):

On Redshift you can create a table to receive the data:

`CREATE TABLE redshift_schema.redshift_table (...);`

Then create a foreign data wrapper, server and a virtual phantom of the table in PostgreSQL RDS:

```
CREATE EXTENSION redshift_fdw;

----optional
--CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER redshift_fdw
--HANDLER postgres_fdw_handler
--VALIDATOR postgres_fdw_validator
--OPTIONS ();

CREATE SERVER redshift_server_mydb
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER redshift_fdw
OPTIONS (dbname 'mydb', port '5439', connect_timeout '200000', host 'myhost.redshift.amazonaws.com');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR mypguser
SERVER redshift_server_mydb
OPTIONS (user 'myrsuser', password 'mypassword');

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA redshift_schema 
LIMIT TO (redshift_table) 
FROM SERVER redshift_server_mydb
INTO postgresql_schema;
```

Now in PostgreSQL you can (in a function if you like) load (select, insert, update, delete) the Redshift table from the PostgreSQL table (without using dblink):

```
INSERT INTO postgresql_schema.redshift_table
SELECT *
FROM postgresql_schema.postgresql_table;
```

Now when you look at the Redshift table all the data is there and you can UNLOAD the table to S3 as required.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code-snippet for that:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM my_table') TO 's3://my-bucket/path' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=*****;aws_secret_access_key=*****' parallel off delimiter ',' ALLOWOVERWRITE ADDQUOTES HEADER ESCAPE gzip;
```

You can check also the following links:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

To export data from a PostgreSQL RDS instance to S3, use the aws_s3 extension: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html

```
CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;

SELECT * from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('select * from sample_table', 
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri('sample-bucket', 'sample-filepath', 'us-west-2')
);
```