# How to export data as a CSV file from a Hasura database?

Tags: database, csv, export, hasura

I have a few tables in the database in a Hasura cluster. I want to export one them as a CSV file (with the data). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow one of the following methods:

1. Connect to the database and use `psql` to export data as CSV:

   a) Directly [access the underlying Postgres db](https://docs.hasura.io/0.15/manual/data/access-postgres.html#accessing-postgres-directly) instance:

   hasura microservice port-forward postgres -n hasura --local-port 6432

   b) follow this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings) to actually export data as a CSV file (assumes you have `psql` installed).
2. Use the data APIs to write a simple service that can convert JSON to CSV and save it to a file.
3. If the size of the table isn't huge, you can also just use the api-explorer UI (either the Data section or the SQL interface) to display all the rows and copy & paste them into a file. It's pretty straightforward to convert this file into CSV format.

Answer (score 3):

Hasura exposes and API endpoint for accessing **pg_dump** of the underlying database.

https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/api-reference/pgdump.html#pg-dump-api-reference

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://<hasura-hostname>/v1alpha1/pg_dump' --header 'x-hasura-admin-secret: <password>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{  "opts": ["-O", "-x", "--schema", "public", "--schema", "auth"],  "clean_output": true}' -o backup.sql
```