# Azure Data Studio: Save As CSV with header

Tags: azure-data-studio

I saw the article on how to save the result of the query as csv.  Is it possible to save it with header?

Reference:
[Azure Data Studio: Save As CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727252/azure-data-studio-save-as-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it always saves the data with headers. You can click on the first icon (see the picture below) on the right side or by right-clicking over the results table to save all the result.

[image]

You also have the possibility to select one or multiple rows (`Ctrl+Click`) from the result table and then do a right-click. It will prompt you a menu with save as CSV, only the selected data will be saved along with headers.

[image]